# How to scrape tables based on keywords in plain text outside the table

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

There's a website which I want to scrape tables from, however, not all tables. Every table has a description that comes before it, in plain text, and I want to make sure I only scrape the tables which are preceded by "GOOD_KEYWORD", however, I also need to know whether tables have been skipped so the program needs to create another column with the index, so that if a table was skipped a number will be obviously skipped.  Not sure where to even begin thinking about this though!

---

---

Website:

> Text Text Text Text BAD_KEYWORD Text Text Text

| Table | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

> Text Text Text GOOD_KEYWORD Text Text Text
> Blockquote

| Table | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |
| Third | row |

---

---

Expected Scraped Result:

| Table | Another header | Table ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | 2 |
| Second | row | 2 |
| Third | row | 2 |

Comment: What is the url of the page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: It's a small private site, that I can't really give an URL to. Is there any info that is missing? I mostly want to understand how to do these things. Just pointing me the right direction would also be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to split the html on the table end tag `</table>`, filter out non-table items from the resulting list, and then extracting only tables that are in the same list item with the good keyword:

```
import pandas as pd

html = '''<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <h2>HTML Table</h2>
      <p>Text Text Text BAD_KEYWORD Text Text Text</p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>Test1</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p>Text Text Text GOOD_KEYWORD Text Text Text</p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>Test2</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>'''

chunks = [i + '</table>' for i in html.split('</table>') if '<table>' in i]

dfs = []

for n, i in enumerate(chunks, start=1):
    if 'GOOD_KEYWORD' in i:
        df = pd.read_html(i)[0]
        df['Table ID'] = n
        dfs.append(df)
```

Output `dfs[0]`:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | Table ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Test2 | Test2 | Test2 | Test2 | Test2 | 2 |